# Firebase dynamic hosting with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've been trying to set the meta tags of Angular2 project when access path using Firebase dynamic hosting. First, I configed the rewrite in firebase.json to call the function in cloud function like this.

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/article-view/**",
        "function": "articleMetaTags"
      }
 ]
```

When client access the path /article-view, it will call the function **articleMetaTags** in cloud function. And this is my clound function

```
exports.articleMetaTags = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

let pid = req.query.text;
const ref = admin.database().ref().child('post/' + pid);
ref.once("value", snapshot => {
        var title = snapshot.val().titlePost;
        var des = snapshot.val().description;
        var image = snapshot.val().featureImage;
        const ref2 = admin.database().ref().child('user-info/' + snapshot.val().ownerPost);
        ref2.once("value").then(usersnap => {
                var user = usersnap.val().username;
                res.status(200).send(`
                <!doctype html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>${title}</title>
                <meta name="og:title" content="${title}">
                <meta name="description" content="${des}">
                <meta name="og:description" content="${des}">
                <meta name="og:image" content="${image}">
                <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
                <meta property="article:author" content="${user}" />
                <base href="/">

                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

                <style>
                .loader {
                border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border-top: 16px solid orange;
                /*border-bottom: 16px solid blue;*/
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top:10%;
                width: 120px;
                height: 120px;
                -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
                animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
                }

                @-webkit-keyframes spin {
                0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
                100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
                }

                @keyframes spin {
                0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
                100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
                }
                </style>

                </head>
                <body>
                <app-root><div class="loader"></div></app-root>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
                <script
                src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
                crossorigin="anonymous">
                </script>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                </body>
                </html>
        `);
        });
});

});
```

In my cloud function, I get the id by GET method and then query the data to set the meta tags in `<head></head>`. Then I send the template of index.html back to client. But the problem is when the template was sent back to client, it doesn't know `<app-root></app-root>`. I think the angular app isn't run. The question is how can I make client run the `<app-root></app-root>` after receive the template from cloud function.